# Monitoring Run queue for AIX in NMON

Tags: performance, aix

I need to know about Run Queue in AIX and how to find the bottleneck of Run queue.

What is the threshold value for Run Queue length?

Answer (score 0):

VMSTAT
r (runqueue) The runqueue value shows the number of tasks executing *and* waiting for CPU resources. When this number exceeds the number of CPUs on the server, a CPU bottleneck exists, and some tasks are waiting for execution.

I believe in AIX this would be a number equal to or less than lcpu.

The run-queue length means "the sum of the number of processes that are currently running plus the number that are waiting (queued) to run."
System configuration: lcpu=16 mem=65536MB ent=4.00

```
kthr    memory              page              faults              cpu
----- ----------- ------------------------ ------------ -----------------------
 r  b   avm   fre  re  pi  po  fr   sr  cy  in   sy  cs us sy id wa    pc    ec
 7  1 8986596 4079422   0   0   0   1    3   0 1017 16130 8195  0  0 99  0  0.03   0.8
```

The server above shows run-queue of 7.  I have lcpu=16.  So it is fine.  Anything above 16 would imply there are processes waiting.  The higher the number the more the wait, the higher perf issues you will find.